# firebase firebaseConfig WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE 1 db.collection is not a function

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase

There firebase firebaseConfig WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE 1 db.collection is not a function when I am trying to create a collection  in my database

I am trying to connect my firestore database (from firebase) and I am trying to create collection in that there are 6 things name, username, previousOccupation, skills and when I trying to connect it, it is giving me a error, Profile.js:33 Error fetching user profile:

TypeError:firebase_firebaseConfig__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.db.collection is not a function

This is my firebaseConfig.js code:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAnalytics } from 'firebase/analytics';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "API_KEY_IS_HERE",
  authDomain: "authDomain_IS_HERE",
  projectId: "projectId_IS_HERE",
  storageBucket: "STORAGE_BUCKETR_IS_HERE",
  messagingSenderId: "MESAGE_SENDER_IS_IS_HERE",
  appId: "APP_ID_IS_HERE",
  measurementId: "MEASURMENT_IS_IS_HERE"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export { auth, db };
```

Profile.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { db } from "./firebaseConfig";

function UserProfile() {
  const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState({
    email: "",
    username: "",
    name: "",
    previousOccupation: "",
    skills: [],
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setUserProfile({
      ...userProfile,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      await db.collection("profiles").add(userProfile); // Store user profile in Firestore
      console.log("User profile created successfully!");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating user profile:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Create User Profile</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Email:</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={userProfile.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Username:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="username"
            value={userProfile.username}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Name:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={userProfile.name}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Previous Occupation:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="previousOccupation"
            value={userProfile.previousOccupation}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Skills (comma-separated):</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="skills"
            value={userProfile.skills.join(",")}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setUserProfile({
                ...userProfile,
                skills: e.target.value.split(",").map((skill) => skill.trim()),
              });
            }}
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Create Profile</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default UserProfile;
```